# How would a trace a packet through a Windows 10 system/network?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I am having a problem using an SSH tunnel I set up from my windows 10 workstation using Putty to a remote linux machine.  I've done this a million times, but recently had Docker for Windows installed on my system.  When I try to send a message using netcat over the tunnel in verbose mode, it hands and I get the message:

```
nc -vvv 127.0.0.1 5001 < message.txt
kubernetes.docker.internal [127.0.0.1] 5001 (?) open
```

I can only assume it is being routed for some reason over the Docker's virtual ethernet adapter and something having to do with Docker doesn't know how to route the packet.  I am at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this.  Is there some way to trace a packet to see how it is being routed and to make sure it is going over the tunnel?  I verified through powershell that Putty is listening on the correct port (5001 in this case.)  It's just when I try to send anything over the tunnel port, it just hangs.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the Docker virtual network adopter temporarily to validate your theory?

Comment: I'm working on that.  My machine is pretty locked down (work machine).  If I can figure out how disable the adapter in elevated mode, I should be able to do it.

Comment: Ok figured out using "netsh" how to do it, but I still get the same message when I disable the adapter.